# Como redirecionar para HTTPS?

Tags: php, redirecionamento

Estou utilizando o *CloudFlare* e minhas URL's com HTTPS já estão funcionando, porém só se eu escrever https://www.exemplo.com se eu não escrever o https, ele continua apontando para o http. Minha hospedagem é *Windows* e fui informado pela mesma de que não poderia utilizar .htaccess para fazer o redirecionamento pois funciona só em linux, alguma sugestão de como fazer para quando acessar a http seja redirecionado automaticamente para o endereço **HTTPS**?

Comment: Se você está utilizando o CloudFlare, você pode fazer isso [pelo próprio adm do site](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170536-How-do-I-redirect-all-visitors-to-HTTPS-SSL-)

Comment: Você também pode utilizar o [Automatic HTTPS Rewrites](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/227227647-How-do-I-use-Automatic-HTTPS-Rewrites-)

Comment: Consegui fazer pelo próprio site do CloudFlare, MUITO OBRIGADO Randrade, muito obrigado cara, não imaginei que poderia ser tão fácil, abraço!

Comment: As vezes as coisas são tão simples que não pensamos fazer dessa forma xD. Fico feliz em ajudar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coloque o script abaixo em um arquivo que é incluído por todas as páginas:

```
if($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on")
{
    header("Location: https://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
    exit();
}
```

Após isso ele vai fazer o redirect automático.

Mas caso deseje você pode fazer isso usando o próprio [cloudflare](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170536-How-do-I-redirect-all-visitors-to-HTTPS-SSL-).

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
function goHTTPS() {
    if ($_SERVER['HTTP'] == "on") {
        $url = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
        $new_url = "https://" . $url . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        header("Location: $new_url");
        exit;
    }
}
goHTTPS();
?>
```